# pass argument to py setup.py bdist_wheel and then read it from setup.py

Tags: python, makefile, visual-studio-2019, setuptools, nmake

In Visual Studio 2019, I have a makefile project in VC++ and using nmake.

In the make.mak file I have below (only showing here a piece):

```
# release build
release: clean
    CD..
    PY -3.8-32 setup.py build_ext--OutputDirectory=$(OutDirectory)
    PY -3.8-32 setup.py bdist_wheel
```

In the project properties, in the build command line, I have the following:

```
nmake /F "$(ProjectDir)..\make.mak" release OutDirectory=$(OutDir)
```

I am using the visual studio macro $(OutDir)
In the make.mak file I have the following setup:

```
setup(
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    packages=['mypackage'],
    ext_modules=[myextmodule],
    cmdclass={
        'build_ext': BuildExtCommand,
    },
    # While not using a pyproject.toml, support setuptools_scm setup.cfg usage,
    # see https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm/#setupcfg-usage
    use_scm_version={
        'write_to': 'src/mypackage/__version__.py',
        #TODO: fallback_version does not seem to work in case os missing tag
        'fallback_version' : '0.0.0-RC0'
    }
)
```

Then in the setup.py file i have defined the class BuildExtCommand:

```
class BuildExtCommand(build_ext)
```

This class contains the methods initialize_options, finalize_options and the run. The run method looks like below:

```
def run(self):
    build_ext.run(self)
```

Finally I initialize the user_options variable:

```
user_options = build_ext.user_options + [
    ('prefix=', None, 'my description here'),
    ('OutputDirectory=', None, 'my description here'),
]
```

Finally with the class I also have a custom method which I get the value from OutputDirectory. This is working for first command in the make.mak file:

```
PY -3.8-32 setup.py build_ext --OutputDirectory=$(OutDirectory)
```

but not working for:

```
PY -3.8-32 setup.py bdist_wheel
```

so how can I pass the argument --OutputDirectory to setup.py bdist_wheel the same I do for setup.py build_ext and then read it from my custom method within the class?

**ATTEMPT #2**:
If i modify the following in the setup:

```
    cmdclass={
        'build_ext': BuildExtCommand,
        'bdist_wheel': BuildExtCommand,
    },
```

and then I execute the following command:

```
PY -3.8-32 setup.py bdist_wheel --OutputDirectory=$(OutDirectory)
```

Then I can read the variable OutputDirectory in the class from my custom method but then i don't know what is happening that bdist_wheel is not creating the directory /dist nor the .whl file is created.